# Facebook Extending life/validity of Access Tokens with the same Access Token (ID/string)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, access-token, facebook-access-token

I am using following API to extend life (validity) of my access token up to 60 days.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?  
    grant_type=fb_exchange_token&           
    client_id=APP_ID&
    client_secret=APP_SECRET&
    fb_exchange_token=SHORT_LIVED_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

using above If I got one access token with 60 days validity e.g : - 
AAACUUypbpertyyZB3dbIevYgzryzbl4ZCUKprtyuilSac7HbGNVR8cHkqDZCS8dfghjklfEmi3HkZA8qgZCVTasdfyz07ZATRsRn5XNH8PAAZDZD

If after 50 days , If I call again the same above Extending API. Here my question is 
Can I extend the validity of same Access Token that i have mentioned above to next 60 days or the new access token will generated by this API ?

ultimately, i want to use the same access token . just i want to extend its validity by 60 days after each 50 days.Please help me on this is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible. From Facebook [Docs](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/):

`The returned access_token will have a fresh long-lived expiration time, however, the access_token itself may or may not be the same as the previously granted long-lived access_token.`